# I have designed an O(logn) algorithm to raise an integer x to the power of n. How to implement this as a recursion in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

The function power(x,n) raises x to a positive integer power n.
My algorithm is following:
Write out n as a sum of power of 2. For example, 27 = 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^1 + 2^0

The essence of the algorithm is a recursive self-squaring one. So x^(2^4) is computed by recursively calling the self-squaring algorithm 4 times.
Here comes the key part: memoizing the result in each recursion in a dictionary, so that x^2,x^4,x^8,x^16 are all in dictionary.

When computing 2^3, which involves self-squaring x three times, we can just look up the dictionary and no computation necessary. Same goes for x^2, and obviously 2^0 = 1

I can complete the code up to here. However, in the end we need to add everything up. I have no idea how to implement the addition part inside the recursive function, as it looks like once you implement the recursion, everything in the function will be recursively called. However we only need the addition once at the end.

Is this even possible to implement this idea as a recursion?

Thank you so much.
----------Adding my incomplete code below---------------------------------

```
def self_square(x,n,power_counter,past_result_dict): 

    if n in past_result_dict: 
        return past_result_dict[n],power_counter
     
    if n == power_counter:
        return x,power_counter

    if (n - power_counter) < power_counter:
        return x,power_counter
    ## This part will need more work for the algorithm to be complete!##
    ## e.g. When n - power_counter < power_counter, we need to set ##
    ## n = n - power_counter, and power_counter = 1, to recurse again##
    ## currently I am giving up and only returning the result up to the power_counter##
    ## so if n = 7, I can only compute up to n=4, and returning from here, instead of recursion on n = 3  ## 
        

    if (n - power_counter) >= power_counter:
        power_counter = power_counter * 2 
        x = x * x
        past_result_dict[power_counter] = x 
    
    return self_square(x,n,power_counter,past_result_dict)

## Trying to run the code with an example. 
x_initial = 3; n_initial = 7
past_result_dict_initial = {0:1, 1:x_initial}
self_square(x = x_initial, n = n_initial, power_counter = 1, past_result_dict = past_result_dict_initial)
```

---

Per my incomplete code above, if I currently run n_initial 7, it can compute only to the rounding down of 2's integer power, that is to the power of 4. I mean I can set up a for loop outside and rerun the function again on n = 3, and in that way I can easily add up the result. However that is ugly! I want to do it inside the one recursion function.

Also, I am  aware of the well-established log(n) algorithm that had been given in some of the answer already. Right now I am obsessed with implementing the version that I wrote above. Although I understand there is no significant advantage, but since I spend so much time on it, I just want to know what is the neat way of writing this out in a recursive python function.

Thanks for your help again.

Comment: In theory, I don't see why any iterative algorithm couldn't be implemented recursively. There may be practical limitations constraints though. Have you implemented your idea iteratively already? If so, can you share it? It would make understanding and answering your question much easier.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend reading through [ask] and how to create a [mre]. You can also take the [tour]. You write "I can complete the code up to here". In the links I've mentioned, you'll see that you should be including your attempt in the question.

Comment: This question is well-formed, clear and interesting. I would work on it, but for lack of time. Perhaps when i have time. It is both an interesting math exercise and would be an interesting task in python. I have too many interesting tasks to complete right now. No need to rephrase this question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be clear: your intent is to compute the, for example, 2nd power of `27 = 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^1 + 2^0`, as `2^(4*2) + 2^(3*2) + 2^(1*2) + 2^(0*2)`? I think you will find that doesn't work, unfortunately. Otherwise, please give more details about the intended algorithm, try to write some of the code, and see *if* and where you get stuck. After [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) you will have the right starting point to ask a *specific* question as described in [ask].

Comment: @user1984  Thank you for your comment. I have added my incomplete code and highlighted where I wish to improve. Hopefully I can make the question more clear.

Comment: If you want a criticism of your (incomplete) code: it is hard to read and understand, and does not express a clean recursion. Using memoization does not seem helpful, as it will work only when you call the function again with the same x. [If the intent is to reuse x^n for the same x and n, you missed a point: when computing x^n, you don't need to compute the same power twice.]

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution {
    public double myPow(double x, int n) {
        
        if(n == 0){
            return 1;
        }
        
        double y = myPow(x, n/2);
        
        if(n > 0){
            if(n%2 == 0){
                return y * y;
            }else{
                return y * y * x;
            }
        }else{
            if(n%2 == 0){
                return y * y;
            }else{
                return y * y * 1/x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a Java solution to recursively find the power of any number. This works for positive and negative powers.

Time Complexity log(n)

This Wikipedia article talks more about it in depth:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Hi, thank you for you suggestion. I have carefully reviewed this already before I posted my question, but I am too obsessed at how I can write out my algorithm in python... I dont think mine is any better than the one you gave, but since I spent so much time on it already, I wish it could be a good exercise for me on recursion.

Comment: Your implementation can take a lot of inverses in the case of negative exponents. Divisions are slow. Better use pow(x, -n) = pow(1/x, n).

Answer (score 1):

If n is even, let 2m, x^n = (x²)^m. If n is odd, let 2m+1, x^n = x (x²)^m.

```
def pow(x, n):
    if x < 3:
        # Low values handled directly
        if n == 2:
            return x * x
        elif n == 1:
            return x
        else:
            return 1

    m= n >> 1
    if n == m << 1:
        # Even power
        return pow(x * x, m)
    else:
        # Odd power
        return x * pow(x * x, m)
```

---

**Personal note:**

I always consider that is it a waste to use a power function for exponents 0, 1 and 2. So I would tend to avoid supporting the case n == 0 to spare a test; I could even skip 1 and 2 and hard-code directly for 3 and 4.

Comment: @Kraigolas: why would you use memoization here ? That would just slow down the computation and consume lots of memory with no benefit.

Comment: @Kraigolas: absolutely not. It always calls itself with different values of the exponent. I guess that you missed the recurrence.

Comment: @Kraigolas: there is no need to time. Understand the method and avoid using memoization "just in case".

Answer (score 0):

Recurse with n x n^(x-1) when x is odd or (n^2)^(x//2) when it is even:

```
def pRaise(n,x):
    if x == 0: return 1
    return n*pRaise(n,x-1) if x%2 else pRaise(n*n,x//2)
```

Or this even more compact version (based on Yves' suggestion):

```
def pRaise(n,x):
    return (1,n)[x%2] * pRaise(n*n,x//2) if x else 1
```

Comment: Micro-optimization: I personally prefer the variant with `n*pRaise(n*n,x//1)` for odd, as it performs less recursive calls.